# How can I center the column vertically in bootstrap mobile mode?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center the first column in the middle vertically , for the mobile mode xs:

```
 <div class="row toplineheight vcenteritems totalblue visible-xs">
    <div class="col-xs-6 vcenteritems small">Your order</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="col-xs-12"><span class="tiny">Upfront</span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 dollar large middle">0</div>
    </div>
```

This is my css(bootstrap 3):

```
.cart {
  .verticalline {
    border-left: thin solid #f7f7f7;
  }
```

At the moment the 'your order' text stays stuck to the top of the div. How can I align this in the center?

Codepen here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/RoYGab/)

Comment: It is mobile mode bs3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the class `visible-xs` on your `.row` element is overriding your `display:flex` css value. Moving the class to a containing element

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOGrWJ)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="cart">
  <div class="visible-xs"> <!-- move visible-xs class to a parent container -->
    <div class="row toplineheight vcenteritems totalblue">
      <div class="col-xs-6 vcenteritems small">Your order</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><span class="tiny">Upfront</span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 dollar large middle">0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><span class="tiny">Monthly</span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 dollar large middle">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, please consider marking my solution as the answer so others may be able to find it when searching :)